# React intercepts /auth/twitter/when HTTPS. I want to access /auth/twitter/ from my node server not the react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, heroku, proxy

New to React/Node.

I have an implementation of React(React-boiler-plate with webpack etc)/Node running on the same host on Heroku.

I am using passport and twitter-oath sessions.
When I hit the endpoint http://example.heroku.com/auth/twitter/callback everything works accordingly (as well as running local dev server).

When I try to access it via HTTPS https://example.heroku.com/auth/twitter/callback React intercepts it and shows a page not found page.

I am trying to get an understanding to understand why this happens and the best way to handle this in a "production" like environment. I would like to be handle /auth/twitter and /auth/twitter/callback all on the same host.

I have tried adding http proxy in misc places as well as package.json and to no avail I am spinning my wheels.

Thank you in advance.

auth routes

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
    // Takes the cookie that contains the user ID and kills it - thats it
    req.logout();
    // res.redirect('/');
    res.send(false);
    // res.send({ response: 'logged out' });
  });
  app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));
  app.get(
    '/auth/twitter/callback',
    passport.authenticate('twitter', {
      failureRedirect: '/'
    }),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  );
  app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    // res.send(req.session);
    // res.send({ response: req.user });
    res.send(req.user);
  });
};
```

index.js

```
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  //
  cookieSession({
    // Before automatically expired - 30 days in MS
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.COOKIE_KEY]
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
// They export a function - they turn into a function - then immediately call with express app object

app.use('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ test: 'test' });
});

setup(app, {
  outputPath: resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
  publicPath: '/',
});

// get the intended host and port number, use localhost and port 3000 if not provided
const customHost = argv.host || process.env.HOST;
const host = customHost || null; // Let http.Server use its default IPv6/4 host
const prettyHost = customHost || 'localhost';

/ Start your app.
app.listen(port, host, async err => {
  if (err) {
    return logger.error(err.message);
  }

  // Connect to ngrok in dev mode
  if (ngrok) {
    let url;
    try {
      url = await ngrok.connect(port);
    } catch (e) {
      return logger.error(e);
    }
    logger.appStarted(port, prettyHost, url);
  } else {
    logger.appStarted(port, prettyHost);
  }
});

console.log('Server listening on:', port);




/**
 * Front-end middleware
 */
module.exports = (app, options) => {
  const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  if (isProd) {
    const addProdMiddlewares = require('./addProdMiddlewares');
    addProdMiddlewares(app, options);
  } else {
    const webpackConfig = require('../../internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel');
    const addDevMiddlewares = require('./addDevMiddlewares');
    addDevMiddlewares(app, webpackConfig);
  }

  return app;
};

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');

module.exports = function addProdMiddlewares(app, options) {
  // messing around here 
  const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
  const apiProxy = proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:3000' });
  const apiProxy2 = proxy('/auth', { target: 'http://localhost:3000' });
  app.use('/api', apiProxy);
  app.use('/auth/*', apiProxy2);
  const publicPath = options.publicPath || '/';
  const outputPath = options.outputPath || path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build');

  // compression middleware compresses your server responses which makes them
  // smaller (applies also to assets). You can read more about that technique
  // and other good practices on official Express.js docs http://mxs.is/googmy
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(publicPath, express.static(outputPath));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(outputPath, 'index.html')),
  );
};

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

function createWebpackMiddleware(compiler, publicPath) {
  return webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    logLevel: 'warn',
    publicPath,
    silent: true,
    stats: 'errors-only',
  });
}

module.exports = function addDevMiddlewares(app, webpackConfig) {
  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  const middleware = createWebpackMiddleware(
    compiler,
    webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  );

  app.use(middleware);
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

  // Since webpackDevMiddleware uses memory-fs internally to store build
  // artifacts, we use it instead
  const fs = middleware.fileSystem;

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(compiler.outputPath, 'index.html'), (err, file) => {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
      } else {
        res.send(file.toString());
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: I can access the api server with any axios.get('/api/current_user') etc, however, if I try to go to that direct url https://example.heroku.com/api/current_user react would then intersect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you have a service worker that is running client side and intercepting the requests, then serving your react app from it's cache.

One hint that gives it away is that the service worker will only be installed / run over https https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

Solution would be to either edit the service worker code to have it not serve for the auth urls or disable it all together if you are not planning to build an app around it, it may be more trouble than it is worth.